# Check if height of entire content in textview is greater than the textview's height

Tags: android, textview

I need to show html content of variable size in a textview for which I am using `Html.fromhtml()` together with an ImageGetter(using Glide). Everything is working fine but I want to limit the size of the textview to say, 150dp, and show an expand button depending on whether the text (including the images) has been cutoff or not. Obviously, I can't use any existing libraries to do this since the set text is a `SpannableString` and also contains images. So is there a way to measure the height of the entire text when the **text is not a pure string but Html content**?